# Finding a minimum of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me to prove that for a fixed number $x>1$,

$$\min_{t\ge 2}\frac{x}{\log(t)}+\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\log(t)}\ge \frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{\log(x)}.$$

Comment: Have you tried taking a partial derivative with respect to $t$ on the left hand side, setting it to $0$?

Comment: i tried to  take a partial derivative with respect to t but i didn't find the result can you please help me?thanks in advance

Comment: This is false - let $x = 1 + \epsilon.$ Then the LHS is bounded above by $ (1 + \sqrt{2} + \epsilon)/\log 2 = O(1), $ while the RHS $ = .5 ( 1+ \epsilon)/\log (1 + \epsilon) \ge .5( 1 + 1/\epsilon) = \Omega(1/\epsilon).$ Thus, as $\epsilon \downarrow 0,$ the LHS is bounded above but the RHS blows up.

Comment: @ stochasticboy321, if so can you please help me to minorate that minimum in function of $x$? thanks

Comment: For certain, exact minimisation would be super messy, and I'm not sure I can manage it. What kind of a lower bound do you need? For instance, the lower bound $x/\log(2)$ is trivial and is stronger than what you wanted for $x$ large enough. Does this suffice? Are you looking for a more refined description as $x \to 1?$ as $x \to \infty?$

Comment: @ stochasticboy321, how to prove that we have the lower bound $x/log(2)$? thanks

Comment: What happened to the solution?  If $x=1.0....001$ and $t=e$ this is surely a counter-example?

Comment: Oh, my mistake, $x/\log (2)$ is incorrect. If you're happy with using some special functions, the unconstrained minimiser of the above is $t_* = x^2/(W(x/e))^2, $ where $W$ is the Lambert-W function. This is always bigger than $2$ for $x >1$ (check this!). After plugging this in, we have that the min is equal to $x/2W(x/e),$ at which point you can start looking for bounds on $W$. For instance, as $u \to \infty,$ $W(u) \sim \log u - \log\log u + o(1),$ so your conjectured inequality is true for large enough $x$.